# How can I properly interpolate a variable as the value of a generated JavaScript value?

Tags: php, javascript

I can't change the value of the text field (with the id "code") to the PHP value (stored in the variable `$code`):

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById('code').value = $code </script>";
```

I also tried `'$code'` and `"$code","..." + "%code + "..."`, but neither helped.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what it outputs?

Comment: Note: the `language` attribute is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: This is really dangerous, a good place for people to hack your app, you're basically allowing anyone to write js on your page. I would consider a redesign. At the very least, be sure that the value in $code is of the expected format.

Comment: `$code","..." + "%code + "..` since you're using + for concatenation you probably use java or javascript.. php concatenates with . dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does $code contain a string?  If so you'll need to quote it.

e.g. if $code equals "my test string", the Javascript will be output like:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById('code').value = my test string </script>";
```

which is invalid Javascript.

You need to:

```
$code = str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST['code']);
echo "<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById('code').value = '$code' </script>";
```

I would also do:

```
$code = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']));
```

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) quotes HTML characters to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: +1 for the right answer here. This is definitely what's causing his problem, just add quotes around $code. Also, as I commented before, this is very dangerous, make sure you sanitize the string as suggested by Michael Boyd. Escaping single and double quotes when putting js into a string will do the trick.

Comment: Yesh! I'm the king of the world! I mean, Andy is ;)
I checked htmlspecialchars documentation and it just converts special characters to  HTML codification. What you are saying here is "replace ' and \ to HTML codification". How does this prevent a XSS attack?

Comment: Because somebody could pass `<script>SendUserToMyFakeWebsite();</script>` into your POST variable, that will get printed as-is into your HTML, and the browser will execute it because it's `<script>`.  Running it through `htmlspecialchars()` will output it as `&lt;script&gt;SendUserToMyFakeWebsite();&lt;/script&gt;` which means nothing to the browser so the user will see the actual script instead of it being executed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
document.getElementById(\"code\").value =". $code. "</script>";
```

Or better yet :

```
<?php
$code = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("code").value = "<?php echo $code;?>";//OR <?= $code;?>;
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for the second option. Avoid echoing HTML if you can help it, it's much easier to maintain if the HTML is just part of the output. Also, if `$code` is a string, it will need to be `document.getElementById("code").value = "<?php echo $code;?>";` and possibly escape the `"` character.

Comment: @Andy E yes Andy I missed that one, fixed it tnx :D

Answer (score 1):

`.value = $code`

to

`.value = '".str_replace("'", "\'", $code)."'`

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't see the `$code` as you've written it. Use this instead:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById('code').value = ".$code."; </script>";
```

or

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "<script language='javascript'>
document.getElementById('code').value = {$code}; </script>";
```

Either more explicitly allows PHP to recognise and parse your string.